# why im getting Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1 in gitlab pipeline creation

Tags: gitlab, yaml, pipeline

commit-message-validator:
stage: validate-commit-message
script:
- echo "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE"
- echo "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
- echo "check the Prefix of the commit message should have one of 'fix' || 'feat' || 'major' || 'minor' in case sensitive"
- exit 1

rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /fix:*/
when: never
- if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /feat:*/
when: never
- if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /major:*/
when: never
- if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /minor:*/
when: never
- if: "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^chore\(release\):.*/"
when: never
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
when: never
- when: always

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nsz7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The last step in your `script` block is `exit 1`. Gitlab CI will fail any job that has an exit code > 0.

The `commit-message-validator` job doesn't currently do any checks, it simply calls `echo` 3 times.  If you want it to check for `fix, feat, major, minor` you will need to do write some logic in the `script` block to do so.